# Restart Nautilus-Instaling Dropbox

Tags: nautilus, dropbox

I'm new with Ubuntu so I hope you can help me. I installed Dropbox using the terminal. Now when I open dropbox to try to log in this message apears:

> restart nautilus

I do it but nothing happens. I tried this but nothing changed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus
sudo apt-get -f install
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: What does adding a third party repository has to do with Dropbox or restart nautilus?

Comment: I read something about installing the latest version of nautilus so I copied this code.

Comment: Unless you mention the specific instructions you follower, I can just say you read what you wanted to read and advise you to remove the repository.

Answer (score 2):

Try `nautilus -q` or `sudo nautilus -q`. Logging out and back in should also restart nautilus.

Comment: I don't think you need to `sudo`, as nautilus usually runs as the logged-on user.

Answer (score 0):

Start Nautilus and close it and start it again.

As soon as my first restart finished following my upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04.1, my machine displayed a dialog box with the message "Nautilus Restart Required Dropbox requires Nautilus to be restarted to function properly."
There was a "Restart Nautilus" button and a "Close" button.

The "restart" button did nothing, but after I clicked "close", I started Nautilus and closed it and started it again, from the Launcher, and Dropbox worked just fine.

Comment: Sometimes, when you install certain extensions like `nautilus-compare`, you may get a message stating that nautilus needs to be restarted, but it doesn't give instructions on how to do this, and you don't have a button to click on.